# Is there a better way to find a user's Start Menu?

Tags: windows, batch-file, special-folders, startmenu

For me, my Start Menu is located at `%appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu`

Is there a system folder reference to use in a batch file that doesn't rely on it being in this place? I would like the script to work for XP and up, but I am running Windows 7.

Comment: Is it okay to write a WScript program that exports the answer to your batch file?

Comment: http://i-broke-it.blogspot.ca/2010/04/taming-all-users-desktop-and-start-menu.html

Answer (score 3):

Joe DF solved this question with this [link](http://i-broke-it.blogspot.ca/2010/04/taming-all-users-desktop-and-start-menu.html) so it works up to Win7; Win8 unavailable for testing at this time. Providing it here so the question no longer shows up as unresolved. From Jim C's solution (see link above):

> Your modified, cross-OS script should read like this and will work
>   properly in both Windows 7 and Windows XP:

```
IF DEFINED PUBLIC (SET AUDESKTOP=%PUBLIC%\Desktop) & (SET AUSTARTMENU=%PROGRAMDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu) ELSE (SET AUDESKTOP=%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Desktop) & (SET AUSTARTMENU=%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Start Menu)
%SystemRoot%\Explorer.exe /n, "%AUDESKTOP%"
%SystemRoot%\Explorer.exe /n, "%AUSTARTMENU%"
```

> Voila! You have a cross [WinXP-Win7] script.

Comment: And what if a future version of Windows moves the Start menu? (After all, it moved between XP and Vista. It may move again.)

Comment: You're correct: Win8 could break it, as Vista and Win7 did. Don't yet have access to a Win8 system, and don't know of a fool-proof way to do this. If I think of one or come across one I'll post back here. This is the best I found so far... :(